# How to use Button_SetElevationRequiredState with QPushButton?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I tried this:

```
QPushButton* openHostsPushButton = new QPushButton("Open Hosts");
Button_SetElevationRequiredState(openHostsPushButton->winId(), true);
openHostsPushButton->setMaximumSize(aPushButtonMaxSize);
connect(openHostsPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
        this, SLOT(openHostsClicked()));
```

However didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, since Qt doesn't actually use native controls but rather custom-draws everything. The only way that Windows will place that icon on a button is if you use a window with the class `Button`, something that you ask the window manager to create for you.

Also note that in order for this to work, you must have included a manifest with your application to link to version 6 of the common controls (Comctl32.dll)—but you should probably be doing that already if you're supporting Windows Vista and 7.

But there's an easier way to do it using Qt involving [`QStyle`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyle.html):

```
QIcon shieldIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_VistaShield);
openHostsPushButton->setIcon(shieldIcon);
```

On systems that do not support UAC, the icon will not appear.

Comment: `setIcon()` is great, but if there is a way to create a QPushButton from a windows PUSHBUTTON?